# threex planets tells me that THREE was not defined

Tags: three.js

the threex- planets- function from here:

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.planets/blob/master/threex.planets.js

tells me that THREE/ three.js was not defined:

"threex.planets.js:406 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined"

This is the particular line:

```
THREEx.Planets._RingGeometry.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Geometry.prototype );
```

Indeed THREE is defined and has already made a scene and several things before reaching this code- line. As THREE is located in the global space and several classes use it without complains I am a bit.... suprised by this error.

I see it is not.... essential to let planets be generated and can be "deleted" and maybe is only needed if I would like to get planetary rings.

What may I be supposed to do to make it work completely ?
After getting this message I just cleaned the code by adding MANY ";" and nothing else.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you loading threex after loading three.js? I would be surprised if this works with the latest three.js as threex.planets has not been updated in 7 years.

Comment: Yes, I do. As I tried to mention, three.js has already built a scene and so on before.
Commenting this line out makes the whole function usable in three.js.
BTW the whole program starts when all js- files are loaded....

Comment: THREE.Geometry removed from the core since r125.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I am still using the release 124...